# Capturing screen shot in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, build-automation

Hi I am not able to capture the screen shot using  selenium   webdriver   .
I get "Unable to get window (NoSuchDriver)".It works fine with Firefox.
I tried running on User1 then it ran well but when I switched to another User ie(User2) switching User
then I get this error

```
   public string TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, string SnapFolderPath, string TCID,   string      KeyFunction)
    {
        ITakesScreenshot ssdriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
        Screenshot screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();
        string filePath = SnapFolderPath + "\\" + TCID + "_" + KeyFunction + "_" + GetDateTimeforFilePath() + ".bmp";
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        return filePath;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Could you include the error message you see?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".But It works fine on Other Login(While Switched to other user)

Comment: what do you mean with users? "It works fine with Firefox" ... "but when I switched to another User ie(User2)"!? do you call your browsers user?

Comment: I have 2 account on my system .ie.UserAccount1 and UserAccount2.WhEn I log onto UserAccount1 and run the code it works fine but when i logoff UserAccount1 and run it on UserAccount2 then I get this error.This happens only for IE.

Comment: What the differences between users? Different browser set up? Are they both admins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it has to do with your internet settings, try this:

Tools > Internet Options... > Security tab, Enable Protected Mode 
checkbox is at the bottom of the tab.

Read this on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-users/6eRU4HIXFfs